# What's the meaning of "our family gatherings are pretty chaotic" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary

What's the meaning of "our family gatherings are pretty chaotic" in this context?

> *Teacher:* Tell me about your family.
>   *Student:* Well, my immediate family is relatively small, just my parents, my two brothers and me. But both of my parents come from very large families so my extended family is very large - I have 25 cousins! **Our family gatherings are pretty chaotic**, but fun. We’re a very close-knit family. Even though we don’t live together any more, the family ties are still very strong. When we were little there wasn’t very much sibling rivalry between us. I think it’s because we had a very stable upbringing. Both of my parents played a very active role in our school life, and our home life, and they taught us to resolve our conflicts in a very fair way. I consider myself very lucky.

Does it mean gatherings in which there are quarrel or something?

Comment: What did two or three dictionaries tell you about *chaotic*?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean gatherings in which there are quarrel or something?

No, it doesn't have a negative meaning and doesn't imply quarelling.

It means that the gatherings are lively, well attended and probably pretty disorganized.

For example, if the speaker has 25 cousins and each cousin has an immediate family of their own (meaning a spouse and probably children) then a gathering could easily number over a hundred people.

That's a lot of people to fit into one space, that's a lot of food to make or to order, that's a lot of gifts to buy, the kids will probably be running around chasing each other. You get the picture...

Comment: Thank you for answering properly.